# Mysql 5.5 LOAD DATA INFILE Permissions

Tags: c++, mysql

**ERROR The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version**

I am having problems migrating some mysqlclient C++ code from Mysql 5.1 to 5.5 (using soci).  The C++ part is not so relevant - the problem is writing some mysqlclient code which can successfully do a LOAD DATA INFILE on MySQL 5.5.

Here are my notes (LOAD DATA INFILE fails, but normal queries are ok):

1. The code below works fine on Mysql 5.1, gcc 4.6.1, Oneiric
2. The same code fails on Mysql 5.5, gcc 4.7.2, Quantal
3. If I LOAD DATA INFILE from mysql (the command-line client), it works fine (I have updated my.cnf with local-infile=1)
4. mysql>  show variables like '%local_infile%';  results in ON

It would be great if there were a SOCI or a configuration solution to this, but if someone has managed to get this to work with libmysqlclient, that would be great to know, too...

---

```
#include <soci.h>
#include <mysql/soci-mysql.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using soci::use;

using namespace std;
using namespace soci;

main()
{
  string val =
    "mysql://"          +
    "host=127.0.0.1"    +
    " dbname=tmp_db"    +
    " user=root"        +
    " password=open_sasame";

    int sum;

    session sql( val );
    sql  << "SELECT 1+1", into( sum );
    cerr << "RESULT=" << sum << endl;     // works fine

    // NEXT LINE FAILS WITH:
    //   The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
    sql  << "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/junk3.txt' INTO TABLE tmp_db.example_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, we need the following line of code:

```
mysql_options( &mysql, MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, 0 );
```

inserted between `mysql_init()` and `mysql_real_connect()`.

Below is a snippet of C code for reference.  Note that SOCI's mysql backend can be patched with this line of code for it to work.

**Tested and works on Mysql 5.5, gcc 4.7.2, Quantal.**

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  MYSQL mysql;

  mysql_init( &mysql );
  mysql_options( &mysql, MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, 0 );
  if ( !mysql_real_connect( &mysql,"127.0.0.1","root","open_sasame","tmp_db",0,NULL,0 ))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to database: Error: %s\n",
      mysql_error( &mysql ));
  }

  if ( mysql_query( &mysql, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/junk4.txt' "
    "INTO TABLE tmp_db.example_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' "
    "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'" ))
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR DURING LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE\n" );
  }

  mysql_close( &mysql );
}
```