# Why LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE will work from the CLI but not in application?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

The problem:

My C++ application connects to a MySQL server, reads the first/header line of each db export.txt, makes a create table statement to prepare for the import and executes that against the database (no problem with that, the table appears just as intended) -- but when I try and execute the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to import the data into the newly created table, I get the error "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version". But, this works on the CLI! When I execute this command on the CLI using `mysql -u <user> -p<password> -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"` it works flawlessly?

The Situation:

My company gets a large quantity of database exports (160 files/10gb of .txt files that are '|' delimited) from our vendors on a monthly basis that have to replace the old vendor lists. I am working on a smallish C++ app to deal with it on my work desktop. The application is meant to set up the required tables, import the data, then execute a series of intermediate queries against multiple tables to assemble information in a series of final tables, which is then itself exported and uploaded to the production environment, for use in the companies e-commerce website.

My Setup:

Ubuntu 12.04

MySQL Server v. 5.5.29 + MySQL Command Line client

Linux GNU C++ Compiler

libmysqlcppconn is installed and I have the required mysqlconn library linked in.

I have already overcome/tried the following issues/combinations:

1.) I have already discovered (the hard way) that LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE statements must be enabled in the config -- I have the "local-infile" option set in the configuration files for both client and server. (fixed by updating the /etc/mysql/my.cnf with "local-infile" statements for the client and server. NOTE: I could have used the --local-infile=1 to restart the mysql-server, but this is my local dev environment so I just wanted it turned on permanently)

2.) LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE seems to fail to perform the import (from the CLI) if the target import file does not have execute permissions enabled (fixed with chmod +x target_file.txt)

3.) I am using the mysql root account in my application code (because its my localhost, not production and this particular program will never run on a production server.)

4.) I have tried executing my compiled binary program using the sudo command (no change, same error "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version")

5.) I have tried changing the ownership of the binary file from my normal login to root (no change, same error "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version")

6.) I know the libcppmysqlconn is working because I am able to connect and perform the CREATE TABLE call without a problem, and I can do other queries and execute statements

What am I missing? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to pass the full real path of file `myfile.txt` ? Did you look into the MySQL server's log files?

Comment: More importantly, and since in practice deployed MySQL servers run on different machines than the MySQL client application, can't you rewrite your application to issue plain `INSERT` statements? Also, are you sure that you did not reach some limit on the size of the request's data?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch :  Actually yes I did use the full path to the myfile.txt but still didn't work... although I should look through the MySQL logs and see if I can find anything.  I understand what you are saying about in practice MySQL servers run on different machines -- however this is a support task to a web server environment -- it will not run in production, it only runs on my local machine.  And yes the first thing I tried was parsing the files and creating inserts -- which takes FOREVER compared to the LOAD DATA INFILE method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much diligent trial and error working with the /etc/mysql/my.cfg file (I know this is a permissions issue because it works on the command line, but not from the connector) and after much googling and finding some back alley tech support posts I've come to conclude that the MySQL C++ connector did not (for whatever reason) decide to implement the ability for developers to be able to allow the local-infile=1 option from the C++ connector.

Apparently some people have been able to hack/fork the MySQL C++ connector to expose the functionality, but no one posted their source code -- only said it worked. Apparently there is a workaround in the MySQL C API after you initialize the connection you would use this:

```
mysql_options( &mysql, MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, 1 );
```

which apparently allows the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statements to work with the MySQL C API.

Here are some reference articles that lead me to this conclusion:

1.) [How can I get the native C API connection structure from MySQL Connector/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409848/how-can-i-get-the-native-c-api-connection-structure-from-mysql-connector-c)

2.) [Mysql 5.5 LOAD DATA INFILE Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133002/mysql-5-5-load-data-infile-permissions)

3.) http://osdir.com/ml/db.mysql.c++/2004-04/msg00097.html

Essentially if you want the ability to use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE functionality from a programmatic Connector API -- you have to use the mysql C API or hack/fork the existing mysql C++ api to expose the connection structure.   Or just stick to executing the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from the command line :(

Comment: Note that I did not try recompiling the MySQL C++ connector -- I just tried to set the flags either in the /etc/mysql/my.cfg file or by the command line option -- try this article if you need instructions on how to recompile the mysql binary: [follow this link ](http://www.sudo-juice.com/install-mysql-5-5-from-source-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: @scones thanks man -- if you or anyone else come up with a pure C++ solution to the mysqlcppconn problem, please let me know --even if its two years from now :)