# MySQL Connector CSV import

Tags: c++, mysql, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file to a MySQL server. Everything is working fine with the MySQL connector: create database, show tables etc. But my program crashes when I create a statement like:

```
stmt->execute("LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\Programming\SQL.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE sqltable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (Company, Address, City)")
```

Who can help me out?

Comment: "my program crash" doesn't provide enough information. What error do you receive?

Comment: I got a debug window which says stop the program or debug the program. I found similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133002/mysql-5-5-load-data-infile-permissions
I use the Oracle mysql connector. In the previous example mysql.h is used. What is the difference and is this a better way to access the sql server?