# How can I get the native C API connection structure from MySQL Connector/C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using the MySQL Connector/C++ to communicate with a MySQL server from a C++ program. For some reason (see below for the background), I need at some point the native C API connection structure. How do I get it from the Connector/C++ classes?

Background:

I want to load a huge amount of data (up to 2-3 billion tuples) from the client's main memory into the server. Therefore, I want to try the LOAD DATA INFILE statement. To avoid to write the whole data to a text file first, I want to define my own local infile handler, which reads the data directly from the main memory.

However, the Connector/C++ comes with no method to set user-defined local infile handlers, but the native C API does. The corresponding C function mysql_set_local_infile_handler() needs a native connection handler (the structure MYSQL) as input parameter. So how do I get this handler from the Connector/C++? Or is there any better way to set the local infile handler in a Connector/C++ environment?

Comment: It definitely is built on Connector/C. Connector/C++ is just an additional wrapper around the native C API (Native C API and Connector/C are two words for the same thing, by the way). It is mentioned several times in the manual, for example here: "The MySQL Connector/C++ is based on the MySQL Client Library (MySQL C API)." (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html)   (Where is the comment gone I replied to!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeConnectionWrapper::mysql`](http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/mysql-connector-cplus-pplus-p/1.1.0~r814/classsql_1_1mysql_1_1_native_a_p_i_1_1_my_s_q_l___native_connection_wrapper.html#a0a93e50136736baf98722022d69e0d61), but it is a private member that is not returned by any method.  Therefore, to access the structure, you will have to fork the Connector/C++ source and compile your own connector.

If that's the path you take, you might prefer to provide access to `mysql_set_local_infile_handler()` from within Connector/C++.

Comment: Too bad. I hoped this would be possible with the "vanilla" Connector.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to work it around via the help of c++ command "system".

1) set the mysql environment in my.cnf: `local-infile=1`. You can find this file here: [how to know mysql my.cnf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location). Or just add option `mysql --local-infile [other options]` in the shell command line mentioned below.

2) In your c++ code, instead of using `stmt->execute(...)` from c++ connector, using

`system("mysql -u username --database=dbname --password=pw -e \"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename INTO TABLE tablename FIELD TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (column1, column2, column3);\"");`

The char array could also be manipulated in the program. Though it seems "low-tech", it does get work done in my project.